# How to search birthday from December to January in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This is for my OJT project. I need to search birthday from MySQL database in DATE type. I already got the query from January to December. The December to January is the problem.

This is what i've done code so far:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['birthday_from']) && isset($_POST['birthday_to'])){

 $start_date=$_POST['birthday_from'];
    $end_date=$_POST['birthday_to'];

     //$s = strtolower($end_date);
    $start_year = date('m-d', strtotime($start_date));
    $end_year = date('m-d', strtotime($end_date));

$search_year = date('Y', strtotime($start_date));
$search_year2 = date('Y', strtotime($end_date));


    $sql=" select * from members where (DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '{$start_year}' AND '{$end_year}') order by DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, '%m-%d') asc ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_row >= 1){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" style="margin:auto;width:900px;"><b><center>BIRTHDAY RESULT</center></b></div>';
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $date = date('Y-m-d')-$rows['birthday'];
                echo '<b><span style="margin-left:20px;">Name:</span></b> '.strtoupper($rows['firstname'].' '.$rows['middlename'].' '.$rows['lastname'].' '.$rows['suffix']).'<br/>';
                echo '<b><span>Birthday:</span></b> '.$rows['birthday'].'<br/>';
                echo '<b><span style="margin-left:30px;">Age: </span></b>'.$date.'<br/><br />';
            }


    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: actually.. what is your problem??

Comment: the problem is when i select date from december to january the result is empty even in database theirs a lot of records.

Comment: your query seems to be okay... chk for the passing values...

Answer (score 2):

1. You do not check the case when start date > end date. It is happens.
2. You named var $start_**year** = date('m-d', strtotime($start_date)), but there is no any Year in value. It is bad practice.
3. You do not use vars **search_year**, **search_year2** after defining and assigning.
4. I do not understand what You want, can You give the example with several rows in table and result what You want to get but You cannot?

Comment: just ignore the variables search_year and search_year2. My query is O.k when the when the search date is from January to December. the problem is when the date is from December to January the query result is empty even in database their is a record.. can you help me?

Comment: I think the right intarval for BETWEEN is from lower to more values. If You need search dates between 15 Dec and 20 Jan, You should add to your query second condition:

Comment: Like this: Between 15-dec and 31-dec OR BETWEEN 01-Jan and 20-Jan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the wrong variables for your `BETWEEN` statement.

```
BETWEEN '{$start_year}' AND '{$end_year}'
```

should be:

```
BETWEEN '{$seach_year}' AND '{$search_year2}'
```

Comment: the variable names threw me for a bit as well. for clarity you could also try switching `$start_year` and `$end_year` to `$start_month_day` and `$end_month_day`